# Get the product list of a given Category ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I couldn't find the right way to get the list of all products for a given category ID (not category name).

The code I am using to get the categories list is the following, it works fine:

```
$args = array(
           'orderby'    => $orderby,
           'order'      => $order,
           'hide_empty' => 0,
           'include'    => $ids,
           'parent'    => 0,
     ); 

$categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
```

However, now for a given category ID (say 47), I couldn't find the way to get its relevant products. I tried the following way:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset'=> 1,
    'category' => 47
 );

$products = get_posts( $args );
echo var_dump($products);
```

Debugging the `$products` array returns always 0 which is wrong since I know there is some products under the category with ID 47. Any ideas how to fix my code?

Comment: `category` or `product_category`?

Comment: you are usifg echo on var_dump. It always show you 0 or 1.  By the way the object has not fetched anything as 0 means false.
The problem is you have not specified any post_type as it will defaults to "post". So there must not be any ID 47 under post's category.

Answer (score 29):

I suspect the main problem is that you should be using the `WP_Query` object rather than `get_posts()`. The later by default only returns items with a post_type of `post` not products,

So given a category with ID 26, the following code would return it's products (WooCommerce 3+):

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => '12',
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => 26,
            'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog', // Possibly 'exclude-from-search' too
            'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

In earlier versions of WooCommerce the visibility was stored as a meta field, so the code would be:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => '12',
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_visibility',
            'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare'       => 'IN'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => 26,
            'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        )
    )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

Here we are only returning visible products, 12 per page.

Have a look through http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters for more details about how the category targeting works - it's often more useful to retrieve it by slug than by ID!

Comment: Solution worked. Nice explanation.

Comment: As of Woocommerce 3, visibility is changed to taxonomy instead of meta so you need to change the meta_query to tax_query. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262628/37355.

Comment: Your conclusion about `get_posts()` is wrong. You can replace `new WP_Query($args)` with `get_posts($args)` in your code and it will work.

Answer (score 23):

```
$products = wc_get_products([
   'category' => get_term($category_id, 'product_cat')->slug
]);
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for getting products using a category ID, however, this helped me, so I'll upvote anyhow. Just be aware it doesn't answer the original question

Answer (score 3):

change category (category-slug-name) by id or name or slug

```
<?php

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 2,'product_cat' => 'category-slug-name', 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'ASC' );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
global $product; 
?>
Within loop we can fetch Product image, title, description, price etc. 

<?phpendwhile;wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but would like to clarify things and provide a cleaner answer. User @benz001 gave a possible valid answer, but said something wrong: `get_posts` returns any kind of post-types, defaulting to `posts` post-type, just like `WP_Query`. The real differences between the two are wonderfully explained [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/90143).

The fact is, the OP was simply missing some parameters into the `$args` array:

- The definition of the post-type he is searching for:

  ```
      'post_type'             => 'product',
  ```
- And the modification of the "taxonomy part" of the search query:

  ```
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'terms' => 26,
              'operator' => 'IN',
          )
      )
  ```

This way your next lines

```
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

Will show you the needed products :)

All other additional parameters shown by @benz001 are of course valid but not requested by the OP, so I decided to leave them behind in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

By using the **get_posts** wordpress function

Get All WooCommerce Product IDs by Category

In below code only need to add the category name and its work.

```
$all_ids = get_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'tax_query' => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'your_product_category', /*category name*/
        'operator' => 'IN',
        )
     ),
  ));
  foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
     echo $id;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when using template file `taxonomy-product-cat.php`

```
$products = wc_get_products(['category_id' => get_queried_object_id()]);
```