# WP_Query: Exclude hidden products from WooCommerce product list

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I hope this is not too specific to WooCommerce.

I have a nifty shortcode that displays a list of all my products with SKUs. However, it also includes products that I have published but have set the catalog visibility to "hidden."

I can't find an argument / parameter to exclude hidden products (or only include those marked as Catalog/Search).

I know it must be simple; I just haven't found it. Thanks for any help.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'menu-order', 'order' => 'asc');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<table class="product-list tablesorter"><thead><tr><th>SKU</th><th>Product Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>
     <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
 <tr>
<td><?php global $product; echo $product->get_sku(); ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
</tr>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php else:  ?>
     <tr><td>
          <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
    </td> </tr>
     <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would note that this code will eventually fail catastrophically due to the `posts_per_page` being set to `-1`. Few servers would handle this code when there are 1000 posts, nevermind 20,000. Multiply that by however many visitors arrive on your site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important:** The following only works for WooCommerce versions less than 3.0. For a more up-to-date answer please see the other [answer by kalle](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262628/7355).

WooCommerce save this data as `metadata` so you'll need to run a [Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) against the name `_visibility`. Something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => '_visibility',
        'value'     => 'hidden',
        'compare'   => '!=',
    )
)
```

This will pull all posts that **do not** have meta `_visibility` equal to `hidden`.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I needed. For anyone who searches for this answer, here is the full query to the above. 

`<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'menu-order', 'order' => 'asc', 'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => '_visibility',
        'value'     => 'hidden',
        'compare'   => '!=',
    )
));
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>`

Comment: @PeterIngersoll FYI, you can mark this answer as accepted to show future visitors what worked for you as well :) There's a check mark on the left of Howdy's answer. Read more here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 24):

As of Woocommerce 3. Visibility is [changed to taxonomy instead of meta](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6.x-to-3.0.0-Developer-Migration-Notes#product-visibility-is-taxonomy-based-instead-of-meta-based). So you need to change the meta_query to tax_query.
To show only visible products,

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'exclude-from-catalog',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
),
```

and examples for Featured Products

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
    ),
),
```

Possible terms: 'exclude-from-search', 'exclude-from-catalog',  'featured',         'outofstock'.