# How to get list of products with category id in WordPress

Tags: php

I have a category id and now I want to get the list of products which have the same category id.

How to do it?

Comment: do you use woocommerce?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143582/get-the-product-list-of-a-given-category-id

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_query' => array(
     'taxonomy' => 'categories name',
     'field'    => 'id',
     'term'     =>  'category id'
     )
);
$the_query = wp_query($args);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?